# How do I set my username in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

When running Mercurial I get this error:

```
t3@des:gem5$ hg qnew my_p.diff
abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")
```

the `hg help config` says:

```
The configuration files use a simple ini-file format. A configuration file
consists of sections, led by a "[section]" header and followed by "name =
value" entries:

  [ui]
  username = Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@example.net>
  verbose = True
```

But where is that ini file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your on linux, create the .hgrc file in either your home directory or in the repository dir in question,

> dirunderhgcontrol/.hg/.hgrc

Add the info(ui, username, verbose...) you stated in your question to the new file and then give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

`hg help config`

> These files do not exist by default and you will have to create the
>   appropriate configuration files yourself: global configuration like
>   the username setting is typically put into
>   "%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini" or "$HOME/.hgrc" and local configuration
>   is put into the per-repository "/.hg/hgrc" file.